# R Automation con Batch File

Tags: r, batch

```
setwd("C:/Users/i.bjazevic_local/Desktop/TESTLATER")

mainDir <- "C:/Users/i.bjazevic_local/Desktop/TESTLATER"
subDir <- "NEWFILES"
setwd(mainDir)
getwd()

dir.create(file.path(mainDir, subDir), showWarnings = FALSE)

library(later)

items <- character(0)
appended_list<-list()


print_new_file_name <- function() {
  items <- dir(pattern = "*.json")
  if(!identical(items, character(0))){
    for(item in items){
      if (!item %in% appended_list){
        appended_list <<- append(appended_list, item)
        print(item)
        file.copy(item, subDir)
      }
    }
  }else{
    print("No json files in folder")
  }
  
  later(print_new_file_name, 5)  
}  

print_new_file_name()
```

El programa trabaja bien con RStudio. Es decir ejecuta, espera por nuevos archivos, y sigue ejecutando.

Sin embargo, cuando hice un BATCH file, solamente ejecuta una vez y se detiene.

No entiendo si estoy haciendo algo mal, o si simplemente no se puede producir con el batch file la misma situación que con RStudio.

Mi plan era poner el batch file en la carpeta STARTUP para que cada vez que inicie el computador el programa arranque. Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Este es el código de mi batch file:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\i.bjazevic_local\Desktop\TESTLATER
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.3\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\Users\i.bjazevic_local\Desktop\TESTLATER\TESTLATER.R" "C:\Users\i.bjazevic_local\Desktop\TESTLATER\TESTLATER.Rout"
```

***Update:***

Encontré que si se modifica el programa para que corra una sola vez, usando la library ***taskscheduleR*** o la library ***cronR*** se puede hacer que el programa corra en el intervalo que deseemos. Sin embargo, me gustaría mucho hacerlo con un batch file. Es posible? Muchísimas gracias por su ayuda!

***Update:***

@RolandoTamayo me pidió que agregue el resultado de la consola. Entiendo que eso está en el Rout file. Gracias por tu ayuda Rolando Tamayo!

El reporte que es producido por R, es decir el Rout file, contiene lo siguiente:

```
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) -- "One Push-Up"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Previously saved workspace restored]

> setwd("C:/Users/i.bjazevic_local/Desktop/TESTLATER")
> 
> mainDir <- "C:/Users/i.bjazevic_local/Desktop/TESTLATER"
> subDir <- "NEWFILES"
> setwd(mainDir)
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/i.bjazevic_local/Desktop/TESTLATER"
> 
> dir.create(file.path(mainDir, subDir), showWarnings = FALSE)
> 
> library(later)
> 
> items <- character(0)
> appended_list<-list()
> 
> 
> print_new_file_name <- function() {
+   items <- dir(pattern = "*.json")
+   if(!identical(items, character(0))){
+     for(item in items){
+       if (!item %in% appended_list){
+         appended_list <<- append(appended_list, item)
+         print(item)
+         file.copy(item, subDir)
+       }
+     }
+   }else{
+     print("No json files in folder")
+   }
+   
+   later(print_new_file_name, 5)  
+ }  
> 
> print_new_file_name()
[1] "1.json"
> 
> proc.time()
   user  system elapsed 
   0.50    0.15    0.59
```

Al analizar los resultados del batch file son los siguientes:

Si dejo el archivo 1.JSON en la carpeta principal, copia el archivo y lo pone en la carpeta NEWFILES. Por cierto, el program crea esa carpeta, si no existe.

Si no hay ningún archivo JSON, se imprime de acuerdo a lo que el programa pide "No json files in folder."

Sin embargo, luego de eso se detiene.

@RolandoTamayo hizo el comentario: ***"Revisaste que el paquete later lo puedas cargar desde R base, los paquetes de RStudio no suelen instalarse en el mismo lugar que los de R base."*** No sé como hacerlo. Sin embargo, hice una prueba con otro archivo instalando usando otra library, y todo trabajó bien. Por supuesto, con otro BATCH file.

***Update:***

Solamente for COMPLETENESS como se dice en el mundo de las matemáticas, publico el archivo final que está funcionando y que probé con el mismo BATCH file usando la respuesta de @Rolando Tamayo

Gracias Rolando Tamayo! Eres un genio!

Estoy seguro que la respuesta final le servirá a personas como yo, que no son tan buenas para la programación.

```
setwd("C:/Users/i.bjazevic_local/Desktop/TESTLATER")

mainDir <- "C:/Users/i.bjazevic_local/Desktop/TESTLATER"
subDir <- "NEWFILES"
setwd(mainDir)
getwd()

dir.create(file.path(mainDir, subDir), showWarnings = FALSE)

items <- character(0)
appended_list<-list()


print_new_file_name <- function() {
  items <- dir(pattern = "*.json")
  print(paste0("my print: ",items))
  if(!identical(items, character(0))){
    for(item in items){
      if (!item %in% appended_list){
        appended_list <<- append(appended_list, item)
        print(item)
        file.copy(item, subDir)
      }
    }
  }else{
    print("No json files in folder")
  }
  
  #later(print_new_file_name, 5)  
  Sys.sleep(5)
  print_new_file_name()
}  

print_new_file_name()
```

Comment: Revisaste que el paquete `later` lo puedas cargar desde R base, los paquetes de RStudio no suelen instalarse en el mismo lugar que los de R base. Tienes acceso a las impresiones de consola que se generan en el batch?

Comment: @RolandoTamayo Hola! Gracias por tu ayuda! Acabo de añadir a la pregunta el resultado de R que está en el Rout file. Que creo que es lo que tú solicitas.

Comment: @RolandoTamayo Sobre tu comentario "Revisaste que el paquete later lo puedas cargar desde R base, los paquetes de RStudio no suelen instalarse en el mismo lugar que los de R base," no sé como hacerlo. Sin embargo, hice una prueba intalando usando otra library, y todo trabajó bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leyendo un poco encontré que `later` crea una tarea en segundo plano en un entorno distinto a `R`,  en `C++`. Esta tarea espera el tiempo indicado y entonces le manda la orden a la instancia de R que ejecute la función que le pasamos.

Lo que sucede en el `batch` es que al correr `later()` r continua su ejecución y eventualmente llega al final del script entonces inmediatamente se cierra la consola y con ello `R`.

Entonces al pasar el tiempo requerido `C++` intenta mandar la orden a la instancia de `R` pero esta ya no existe.

Por lo anterior no creo que sea posible lograr lo que requieres usando `later`, no por esto `later` deja de tener otras aplicaciones interesantes.

**Propuesta de solución usar Sys.sleep**

He logrado que el programa funcione con el batch modificando la función print_new_file_name como se ve a continuación:

```
print_new_file_name <- function() {
  items <- dir(pattern = "*.json")
  print(paste0("my print: ",items))
  if(!identical(items, character(0))){
    for(item in items){
      if (!item %in% appended_list){
        appended_list <<- append(appended_list, item)
        print(item)
        file.copy(item, subDir)
      }
    }
  }else{
    print("No json files in folder")
  }
  
  #later(print_new_file_name, 5)  
  Sys.sleep(5)
  print_new_file_name()
}
```

Con `Sys.sleep()` le decimos directamente a `R` que suspenda su ejecución durante determinado perdido en segundos. Una vez trascurrido este periodo `R` continua su ejecución y encuentra inmediatamente otro llamando a la función `print_...` generando a si una función recursiva que se ejecutara a si misma indefinidamente.

Comment: Eres un genio! Lo voy a probar! Gracias!

Comment: Está funcionando! No sabes cuánto te lo agradezco! Cuando no me funciona algo, no puedo dormir :):):):):)